# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:3.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How to fix this ,i really dont know how to fix this
below is the snipped code that i got on event log

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:3.3.2.
        Searched in the following locations:
        - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.3.2/gradle-experimental-3.3.2.pom
        - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.3.2/gradle-experimental-3.3.2.jar
        - https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.3.2/gradle-experimental-3.3.2.pom
        - https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.3.2/gradle-experimental-3.3.2.jar
        - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.3.2/gradle-experimental-3.3.2.pom
        - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.3.2/gradle-experimental-3.3.2.jar
        Required by:
        project :
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (24 s 518 ms)

> Blockquote
```

Comment: what is your `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle`?

Comment: Check if your studio requires a proxy to access these files.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your android gradle plugin version as below from the top level `build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```